# Is it possible to edit the font-family of tooltips on a browser?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, fonts

`rikaikun` (with symbol 理 at the top right corner) is Chrome's addons to show the description of a word being highlighted.

[image]

## Question

Unfortunately `rikaikun` does not show the stroke order of the Kanji characters. As the stroke order is important, if possible, I want to hijack it, change the `font-family` to `KanjiStrokeOrders` font (available [here](http://www.nihilist.org.uk/)).

Is it possible to do so? How?

Comment: Use css @font-face. Check relative documentation on the web

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy: How to hijack the addons?

Comment: Addons are dependent on chrome extension APIs. Same, search on the web, you wil find more

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy: There should be a configuration file for `rikaikun` that can be edited. But I do not know where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that were actually a tooltip, the answer would be "no". Tooltips are rendered by the OS, and do not support any formatting.

However, what's shown in the picture isn't a tooltip! It's an HTML element injected into the document by the extension. It clearly already has some CSS styling applied to it (e.g, coloring certain words), so I see no reason why you couldn't extend that.